# find the intersection of abline with fitted curve

Tags: r, point, curve-fitting, logistic-regression

I plotted a logistic curve with its fit using the following codes:

> data:L50
>
> `str(L50)`
>
> 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
>
> $ Length.Class: int  50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140
>
> $ Total.Ind   : int  9 20 18 8 4 4 1 0 1 2
>
> $ Mature.Ind  : int  0 0 6 5 3 2 1 0 1 2
>
> `plot(L50$Mature.Ind/L50$Total.Ind ~ L50$Length.Class, data=L50,pch=20,xlab="Length class(cm)",ylab="Proportion of mature individuals")`
>
> `glm.out<-glm(cbind(L50$Mature.Ind, L50$Total.Ind-L50$Mature.Ind) ~ L50$Length.Class,family=binomial(logit), data=L50)`
>
> `glm.out`
>   Call:  glm(formula = cbind(L50$Mature.Ind, L50$Total.Ind - L50$Mature.Ind) ~ 
>       L50$Length.Class, family = binomial(logit), data = L50)
>
> Coefficients:
>        (Intercept)  L50$Length.Class
>            -8.6200            0.1053
>
> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
>   Null Deviance:      38.14 
>   Residual Deviance: 9.924        AIC: 23.4
>
> `lines(L50$Length.Class, glm.out$fitted,type="l", col="red",lwd=2)`
>
> `abline(h=0.5,col="black",lty=2,lwd=2)`

I got the following curve:
[image]

The question is that i need to find the point that corresponds to Y=0.5 on the fitted curve and draw a line segment through it with its value on the x-axis....Any help with that?
Thank you

This is what you asked

`dput(L50)`

`structure(list(Length.Class = c(50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 
110L, 120L, 130L, 140L), Total.Ind = c(9L, 20L, 18L, 8L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), Mature.Ind = c(0L, 0L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L), MatF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L), MatM = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Length.Class", 
"Total.Ind", "Mature.Ind", "MatF", "MatM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coefficients say that `y = -8.62 + 0.1053x`, so `x =  (glm.out$family$linkfun(.5)+8.62)/ 0.1053`.  Having said that, you'll probably want to use a well documented function, such as `dose.p(myFit, 0.5)` from the `MASS` package, so that you also get standard errors etc.

Comment: 86 is a very high value if you can notice from where the abline intersects with the fitted curve.

Comment: OK - what does the `dose.p` call I suggest give you?

Comment: > dose.p(glm.out$fitted, 0.5)
Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: i did it by hand and the answer should be 81.86cm. This is a logistic function and not a linear one.

Comment: you need `dose.p(glm.out, 0.5)`

Comment: Your 'by hand' calculation presumably fits to the lines you've interpolated on your graph - the underlying prediction curve is smooth, which might influence things.  Your fitted object should have the inverse in glm.out$family should have the link function that you can call to transform the 0.5 that I initally put in the equation.

Comment: dose.p(glm.out, 0.5)
Error in pd %*% vcov(obj)[cf, cf] : non-conformable arguments

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(L50)` into your question, so we can recreate your exact example easily?

Comment: Ah, sorry yes - The usage should actually be `dose.p(glm.out, p=0.5)`, which is effectively replacing 0.5 with loglink(0.5) in the original version of my answer - I'll update the original in case anyone else needs it